# How to align grids in foundation 6.4?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

How do I align grid items in Foundation 6.4? I want some contents to be right aligned (or end-aligned), and others to be vertically centered, or bottom aligned for example.

I can't find any mention of a class in the official docs, and previous techniques (< 6.4), like `align-right` or `end` do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZURB Foundation "**Flexbox Utilities**" makes horizontal and vertical alignment painless, through CSS properties.

[Read all about the Horizontal and Vertical Alignment CSS class names >>](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/flexbox-utilities.html)

Comment: Thanks. That page doesn't come up if you type `align` or `align-right` in the search box. That's why I couldn't find it.

Answer (score -2):

Everything you would ever want to know about aligning items using the new Foundation XY Grid in v6.4 can be found on the ZURB YouTube Video Channel.

Take a look [at this YouTube Video >>](https://youtu.be/Xl5DjEzKn1g)

Comment: I'm sure it's a nice video, but I can't search through it. I was hoping for a written reference.

Comment: You will find the written detail on the ZURB Foundation website. Surely you have made the basic effort to search for that ?

Comment: No, it's not there in the docs. Search for "align" and you don't find details on how to align things in the grid.